# HTML form input dependent on previous form input with javascript and php, not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have been trying to create some select inputs that depend on the previous input in an html form using HTML Javascript PHP and MYSQL. This has worked with one of my previous pages, and so when creating this new one I just defined a new function in the javascript file and created a new php file to send data to as I wanted to output something different for the last select box in the form.

Even though I mirrored the previous function and php file changing only a few minor details, I am not able to see any of my created options for the last dropdown select and I dont seem to be getting any errors practically a blank php page with no errors is getting passed through, and I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is a screenshot of my form and you can see the 'Rack Unit Location' option does not create any options and is blank yeth the other select boxes work fine:

[Form Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6F8I.png)

This is the section of my HTML form, so I want Rack Unit Location to depend on Rack Number, which depends on Location and in turn depends on Rack.

```
<tr>
    <th>Rack </th>  
    <script src='includes/Jquery/default.js'></script> <!-- Link to new Javascript file -->
    <td>    
        <select id='rack_name' name="rack_name" onchange="window.loadLocation()">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Rack Name</option>
        <?php
            $r = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_network Like 'rack%'"); 
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
                echo "<option value=".$row['Tables_in_network'].">".$row['Tables_in_network']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
        <option value="no_rack">Not in Rack</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Location</th>
    <td>
        <select id="location" name="location" onchange="window.selectrack()">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Location</option>                           
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Rack Number</th>
    <td>
        <select id="rackno" name="rackno" onchange="window.selectpduunit()">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Rack Number</option>        
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Rack Unit Location</th>

    <td>
        <select name="rackunit" id="rackunits">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Rack Unit Number</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Those onchange functions are defined in the following Javascript file:

```
function loadLocation(){    
var formName = 'switch';
var rackname = document[formName]['rack_name'].value;

var xmlhttp = null;
if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'udefined'){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else if(typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined'){
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}else{
    throw new Error('You browser doesn\'t support ajax');           
}
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'load_location.php?rack='+rackname, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        window.insertLocation(xmlhttp);
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function insertLocation(xhr){
    if(xhr.status == 200){
    document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }else{
    throw new Error('Server has encountered an error\n'+'Error code = '+xhr.status);
    }
}

function selectrack(){    
    var formName = 'switch';
    var rackname = document[formName]['rack_name'].value;
    var location = document[formName]['location'].value; 
    var xmlhttp = null;
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined'){
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }else {
        throw new Error('You browser doesn\'t support ajax');           
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'select_rack_number.php?location='+location+'& rack='+rackname, true);  
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
             window.insertrackno(xmlhttp);
     };
     xmlhttp.send(null);
 }

function insertrackno(xhr){
     if(xhr.status == 200){
        document.getElementById('rackno').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
     }else{
        throw new Error('Server has encountered an error\n'+'Error code = '+xhr.status);
     }
 }

 function selectrackunit(){    
     var formName = 'switch';
     var rackname = document[formName]['rack_name'].value;
     var location = document[formName]['location'].value; 
     var rackno = document[formName]['rackno'].value; 
     var xmlhttp = null;
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'udefined'){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined'){
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }else{
    throw new Error('You browser doesn\'t support ajax');
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'select_rack_unit.php?location='+location+'&rack='+rackname+'&rackno='+rackno, true);   
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
            window.insertrackunit(xmlhttp);
     };
    xmlhttp.send(null);
 }

 function selectpduunit(){    
    var formName = 'switch';
    var rackname = document[formName]['rack_name'].value;
    var location = document[formName]['location'].value; 
    var rackno = document[formName]['rackno'].value; 
    var xmlhttp = null;
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'udefined'){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined'){
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }else{
         throw new Error('You browser doesn\'t support ajax');
    }
     xmlhttp.open('GET', 'select_pdu_unit.php?location='+location+'&rack='+rackname+'&rackno='+rackno, true);   
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
         if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
             window.insertpduunit(xmlhttp);
     };
     xmlhttp.send(null);
 }

function insertrackunit(xhr){
    if(xhr.status == 200){
        document.getElementById('rackunits').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }else{
        throw new Error('Server has encountered an error\n'+'Error code = '+xhr.status);
    } 
}

function insertpduunit(xhr){
    if(xhr.status == 200){
        document.getElementById('rackunits').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
     }else{
         throw new Error('Server has encountered an error\n'+'Error code = '+xhr.status);
     } 
 }
```

And here is the code in the php file that doesn not seem to be working for the selectpduunit function:

```
<?php
require 'includes/opendb.php';  
if(isset($_GET['location']) && ($_GET['rack']) && ($_GET['rackno']) )
{      
    $b = $_GET['location'];
    $e = $_GET['rack'];
    $d = $_GET['rackno'];
    $first_unit='1';
    $explode=explode('-',$e);
    $last_unit=$explode[1];
    var_dump($b);       
    var_dump($e);       
    var_dump($d);
    var_dump($explode);

        while($first_unit<='4'){ //While Loop creates port columns in new table for each port on PDU.
            if('10' > $count){
                $column [] = '`PDU-0'.$first_unit.'`,'; //Storing port number as string in array."`port-0".$count."` varchar (255) NOT NULL";
            }else{
                $column [] = '`'.'PDU-'.$first_unit.'`'.',';
            }
            ++$first_unit;

        }
        $empty = '';
        foreach($column as $c){
            $empty = $empty.$c; 
        }
        //$empty = rtrim($empty2, ",");

    $select="SELECT $empty FROM `$e` WHERE location = '$b' AND `Rack-Number` = '$d'";       
     var_dump($select); // Outputs the above generated MySQL string
    if(!mysqli_query($conn,$select)){
        die("Error".mysqli_error($conn));
    }else{
        $r = mysqli_query($conn,$select);
    }
    $unit_1 = '1';
    while ('4' >= $unit_1){
        if($unit_1 <'10'){
            $column1[] ='PDU-'.'0'.$unit_1;
        } else{
            $column1[] ='PDU-'.$unit_1;
        }
        ++$unit_1;
    }
    //var_dump($column1); // Outputs the above generated strings. The string should be column names.

    $rackunit ='';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))  {
        if($e == 'no_rack' || $e == 'vm_rack'){
            //$rackunit =$rackunit.'<option value="'.$row["Unit"].','."Unit".'">'.'('."Unit".')'.' '.$row["Unit"].'</option>';      
            echo "fail";
        }else{
            foreach($column1 as $c1){
            $rackunit =$rackunit.'<option value="'.$row["$c1"].','.$c1.'">'.'('.$c1.')'.' '.$row["$c1"].'</option>';            
            }
        }   
    } 
    var_dump($rackunit);
    if($rackunit == '')
        echo 'An Error has occurred. Dropdown Menu is not being populated.';
    else
        ?>      
            <select name="rackunit" id="rackunit">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Rack Unit Number</option>
                <?php echo $rackunit ?> 
                <option value="1">Test</option>
            </select>
        <?php  

}   

?>
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. In method selectpduunit as well as selectrackunit

```
 if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'udefined'){
```

It should be instead

```
 if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'){
```

May be because of that you are not able to create a new XMLHttpRequest object. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, changed it but still facing the same issue